# Sorting a array's numeric values without re-indexing (PHP)

Tags: php, sorting

What I'm doing is this:

- I get a list of ID values (numeric) from the DB and store it into an array (1, 2, 2, ...)
- I then count the duplicates with `array_count_values`. this outputs ([1]=>1, [2]=>2, ...)
- I then want to reorder the array in a descending order via the count
- I then just use `array_keys($array)` to get the IDs in a count ordered list.

I once used `array_multisort` for a similar function but in that case the keys were strings ('a'=>2). The problem now is that I'm using numeric keys and multisort re-indexes the keys to 1, 2, 3 because the keys holding the count value are numeric IDs. This of course screws the purpose 'cause I can't identify anything anymore..

Anyway, here's what I'm roughly doing now:

```
$array = array(3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3);
// count the IDs [0]=>3, [1]=>1, [2]=>2

$count = array_count_values($array);

// sort and screw up the id's: [0]=>3 [1]=>1 [2]=>2
array_multisort($count);
```

Something tells me that there's a better way of approaching this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`asort`](http://php.net/asort) instead of `array_multisort` as it maintains the original index association.

Comment: Thanks... that was simple but is there any easy way to sort it in a descending list? My original use of multisort was because of this.

Comment: @transient-jet-lag: You can either use `arsort` (`r`=reverse) or use `array_reverse` after `asort`.

Answer (score 2):

Guessing from your first sentence:

> I get a list of ID values (numeric) from the DB and store it into an array (1, 2, 2, ...)

perhaps you could do the sorting whilst querying, something like this:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id) AS quantity FROM table GROUP BY id ORDER BY quantity DESC
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. There you go, I always miss the most obvious thing.

Comment: Yeah you did, but giving a detailed background on the question is the next best thing :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to do it with php? Change your SQL statement to give you the correct results. something like

```
select ID, count(another_col) as occurrence
from table
group by ID
sort by occurrence
```

For the right SQL syntax see http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php

edit: ups missed the sorting criteria. It must be by occurrence and not by ID

Comment: You are rigth, with group by it needs to be order by. How can I have missed that? ;)

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, if you can get the data sorted from the database, it might be better. If You want to do it in PHP and need reversed order, use `[arsort][1]`.

Answer (score 0):

There are valid use cases where you might not be able to pre-sort result sets in your query and need to use array_multisort. Here's an example of how you might go about doing so while maintaining your original key association.

```
// Let's say your data is a hash lookup where the key is important.
$user_ids = array_keys($users);
// You want to sort by username so copy those values.
$usernames = array_column($users, 'username');
// Now sort your arrays.
array_multisort($usernames, SORT_ASC, $user_ids, $users);
// Simply recombine your keys and values.
$users = array_combine($user_ids, $users);
```